# How do I identify the protein with the highest Disulfide bond density? i.e protein with highest ratio of Disulphide bonds per Peptide bond?

Tags: bioinformatics, proteins, protein-folding, protein-structure

I want to list all proteins in the protein database and list them by the ratio of number of disulphide bonds per peptide bond. 
I am not particular about the reliability of identification of disulphide bond.

--EDIT 1
I've been doing some research on this topic, and heres what i've found.

1. The PDB structure file lists all the Disulphide bonds in each structure.(SSBOND)
2. The PBD structure file does not list the number of peptide bonds, however it does 
   mention the number of amino acids. And number of peptide bonds = [no. of amino acids - 1].
3. We can generate a list of all PDB structure IDs with atleast 1 disulphide bond, using PDB.org's advanced search feature. This gives a list of 22543 structures.
4. Downloading all the 22543 structures and then parsing them using any programming language would be easy, except for the difficulty of downloading all the 22543 sturctures.

So the question now is: 
 How do I parse all the 22543 structures to output only the number of disulphide bonds and the number of amino acids in each chain, without downloading the PDB structure files?

Comment: Count the number of cysteines and divide by total number of amino acids- that would be a not so reliable method.

Comment: That is the obvious answer for a single protein. I am looking for a way to do it across all the proteins in the PDB.
Essentially I want a way to query the number of Disulphide bonds from all proteins and the number of amino acids from all the proteins, and print a list.

Comment: You can download all sequences from the PDB in one file: ([gzipped fasta format](ftp://ftp.wwpdb.org/pub/pdb/derived_data/pdb_seqres.txt.gz))

Comment: Thanks Mad Scientist, I did not realize that it would be such a small file. I guess i'll have to do a little bit of coding to get the rest of the answer.

Comment: @user8338 for PDB files you can actually find real disulphide bonds instead of counting cysteines. They would be annotated. If you are looking at all possible disulphide bonds, you can download the Refseq protein fasta file and count cysteines

Comment: @user8338 Parsing is a programming question and is off-topic; suitable for stackoverflow. However you should make an attempt at it before asking in SO.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about text-parsing.

Comment: @WYSIWYG I agree the text-parsing part is off topic. My problem is about if it can be done on any server without me downloading the text files.

Comment: @user8338 I don't think so. The files are not that huge; you can download them without any problem.

Comment: @WYSIWYG the complete list of 22543 PDB files is in an excess of 2GB, compressed as gzip. I've been trying since last night to get them as a compressed file, and failed. Now I'm trying to download them uncompressed.

Comment: @user8338 Try doing with wget if you have a linux system. It is also available for windows with the GNUwin32 package.